# Given type and number of carbon atoms and degree of unsaturation of a hydrocarbon, write structural formula

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrocarbons, structural-formula

Write a structural formula of the hydrocarbon that contains 4 primary carbon atoms, 2 ternary carbon atoms, 3 quaternary carbon atoms, and has degree of unsaturation 3.

This has been given at the chemistry test today. Only one person succeeded the problem.

Correct solutions are:

[image]
[image]

In my attempts I made a triangle and a square, but none of them seemed to work to satisfy the type of carbon atoms and I stopped.

My question is - is there any algorithm to solve this type of problems, or are there any other information that we can extract from the problem to help us draw the structural formula, aside from the number of hydrogen atoms (in this case, 14)?

As an unexperienced programmer who worked with graphs, I can only imagine a brute force for the bonds. For example, a ternary carbon atom could have a triple bond, or a single and a double. The primary carbon atoms are easy to solve, we must link them to a single bond, but how about the other ones? Is there an official software for this type of computations?

We have just begun organic chemistry, and the teacher missed 4 classes, that is 8 lost hours of chemistry that we do not recover. Please understand that I am an organic chemistry noob.

Thanks!

Comment: This solution is a blatant, outrageous, malignant nonsense. As for the general approach, brute force will do.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin. Why do you call it nonsense ? I agree the bent C=C=C bonds are non realistic. But why call it a non-sense ?

Comment: @Maurice Because profane swearing is forbidden here, or so I was told.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Sorry, I did not know it is impossible to bend C=C=C, no one told me. I have edited the post providing another formula.

Comment: Now that's another story.

Comment: If you have a sum formula then you indeed can generate/write down quite a number more or less plausible molecules. The numbers of entries may be huge (e.g., [GDB13](https://gdb.unibe.ch/downloads/)), and imposing any structural features may reduce them greatly (e.g., [molgen](https://molgen.de/online.html) as one of the [generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_graph_generator)) to sets easier to manage, e.g., in [mass spectroscopy](https://fiehnlab.ucdavis.edu/projects/Seven-Golden-Rules).

Answer (score 1):

This answer will give you little insight about chemistry, and maybe a little insight into problem solving strategies.

> The primary carbon atoms are easy to solve, we must link them to a single bond, but how about the other ones?

This is a good insight. The entire structure has 9 carbons and 14 hydrogens. To simplify it, we can replace the 5 methyl groups by hydrogen, giving us the formula $\ce{C5H4}$. This core structure will harbor the rings and double/triple bonds, and the methyl groups can be added later.

> For example, a ternary carbon atom could have a triple bond, or a single and a double.

Rather than going for an by-atom strategy, it might make sense to think about the total number of double and triple bonds as well as rings. The degree of unsaturation is three. Each double bond and ring contributes one while a triple bond contributes two. For a total of three, you could have:

- a triple and a double bond
- a triple bond and a ring
- three double bonds
- two double bonds and a ring
- one double bond and two rings
- three rings

With five carbon atoms to work with, three double bonds implies an allene. Here are some examples of the structures you would start with. With the small numbers, it might not be necessary to use an algorithm. Many of these are ridiculously strained, so there would have to be a filter to remove the impossible structures.

[image]

#### Adding the methyl groups

To each of the 5-atom structures you would have to add the methyl groups (replace a hydrogen with a methyl group) in a way that no CH2 groups remain. Sometimes, there are multiple ways and sometimes there is only one. In the end, you get more than the two example structures, some of which are plausible (for example, the structures with a triple and a double bond lacking any rings).